# Earth Engine satellite view refresh rate

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

How often does the satellite view in the Google Earth Engine get refreshed?
I know that the Landsat refresh rate is 16 days. But is this the same for the satellite view on the map in Earth Engine?

[image: satellite view in Earth Engine]

Comment: @user2856 Your comment is correct and should stand as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The “satellite” view seen on the map in Earth Engine's *Code Editor* (it is not otherwise available in Earth Engine) is the same one used for Google Maps and Google Earth. It is a composite of many images (satellite and aerial) and it is updated based on interest in various areas, not on a regular schedule. It is not suitable for scientific analysis — think of it as being “for reference” so you can put your image results in context of familiar landmarks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wanted to edit the question to ask if I could find or create a similar thing for analysis. However it seems there are questions that have been asked here(stack exchange) already. Thanks for the assistance given.